# multiple string filtration on columns - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem excluding `avg_price_m2` from first group of columns. Both groups technically start with "`avg_price`" - but I would like to exclude those, which start with "`avg_price_m2`" from the first group.

```
columns = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.startswith("avg_price")].columns.tolist()
columns_m2 = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.startswith("avg_price_m2")].columns.tolist()
```

---

I need it in that format (list) as I am using it later to calculate weighted average like that:

```
weighted_avg_m2 = df[columns_m2 + ['date', 'available_offers_with_prices_m2']].groupby('date').apply(
                lambda x: weighted_average(x, 'available_offers_with_prices_m2', columns_m2))

weighted_avg = df[columns + ['date', 'available_offers_with_prices']].groupby('date').apply(
                lambda x: weighted_average(x, 'available_offers_with_prices', columns))
```

Comment: Maintain 2 separate variables which are just list of columns and use it later? You can do all kind of string processing in a list

Answer (score 1):

You just have to remove the contents of the second list from the first one

```
columns = [i for i in columns if i not in columns_m2]
```